# Component published property like TFont.Name

Tags: delphi, components

I wrote below unit for a sample component :

```
unit Test;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Variants, VCL.Dialogs;

type
  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    fName: TStringList;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); Override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Names: TStringList read fName;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTest]);
end;

{TTest }

constructor TTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fName := TStringList.Create;
  for i:= 1 to 100 do
      fName.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  fName.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Now when I install it on Delphi, in the Object Inspector I have a property named "Names", I should double click on it then a dialog shows the TStringList's items stored on Name.

I would like to make this property like Font.Name in other components (like TEdit and etc), when click on Name property , a list shows and user can select an item from it, then the item is assigned to the property and show as property value in the Object Inspector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a property editor for your property. Here are some links for you to read as it's not a simple answer:-

http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/property.htm

http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc092501a.htm

http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/comps1.htm